# Ansible vars_prompt for host list into Import_playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to use a specific host / host list for an imported playbook which I get from a vars_prompt input. How can I do this? So far I wasn´t able to get this running.

I have two playbooks which I need to run separately and ios_check_routerports.yaml is the parent playbook:

ios_check_routerports.yaml

```
---
- hosts: '{{ branch_number }}'
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: False
  any_errors_fatal: no
  throttle: 75
  
  vars_prompt:
  
    - name: "branch_number"
      prompt: "Which branch do you want to check?"
      default: all
      private: no
tasks:
 
    - name: Check facts
      ios_facts:
        gather_subset: hardware
  
    - name: Create directory
      file:
        path: /root/ansible/pb-outputs/ios_check_routerports/
        state: directory
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: Run playbook
  import_playbook: ios_check_routerports_main.yaml
```

ios_check_routerports_main.yaml

```
---
- hosts: '{{ branch_number }}'
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: False
  any_errors_fatal: no
  throttle: 75

  tasks:
  
    - name: Check default-gateway
      ios_command:
        commands: sh run | i default-gateway
      register: default_gateway
```

I tried to set a fact for the var {{ branch_number }} like this:

ios_check_routerports.yaml

```
- set_fact:
          devices: "{{ branch_number }}"
```

ios_check_routerports_main.yaml

```
---
- hosts: '{{ devices }}'
  connection: network_cli
```

The playbook always runs into an error because the hosts var is not defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: no need to create a new variable devices but a dummy host

in ios_check_routerports.yaml add a task:

```
- name: Register dummy host with variable
  add_host:
    name: "DUMMY_HOST"
    DEVICES: "{{ branch_number }}"
```

then :

```
- hosts: "{{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['DEVICES'] }}"
  connection: network_cli
```

as you create a new host, i suggest you to delete it if you havent need the variable branch_number so remove_host doesnt exit:

either you do a first task     `- meta: refresh_inventory`

or you modify your host like this:

`- hosts: "{{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['DEVICES'] }},!DUMMY_HOST"`